# Running a calculation function for n number of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automate a calculation for a measurement data Excel file.

While I made the function work, I could only figure out how to do that for one row at a time. The calculation is specific to the data on every row.

I thought I could change the `Range("J3")` value to `Range("J3:J52")` for a capacity of 50 calculations.

How do I make the function calculate for every row, separately, using the data of said specific row?

It doesn't matter if it runs for all 50 rows or if I have to figure out some loop function to find how many rows to calculate for, as long as one button press in the end will make the magic happen.

I have included a screenshot of the sheet for reference, the main calculation is done in Excel, but what this is doing is choosing the correct option out of a few different correction calculations and explaining to the user why.

I think there are some unnecessary Dim lines at the start but if it runs, I wasn't going to remove them.

[image]

```vb
'The main function, activated by a simple button Sub'
Function ISO16032()

    'DeltaL Range'
    Dim DeltaL As Range
    Set DeltaL = Range("F3")
    'Result is the corrected value in G column'
    Dim Result As Long
    'Note is the calc note in H column'
    Dim Note As String
    'X is the DeltaL between noise and background noise'
    Dim x As Long
    x = Range("F3").Value
    
    Select Case Range("F3").Value
    
        'No correction when X = > 10'
        Case 10.6 To 200
            Result = Range("J3")
            Range("G3").Value = Result
            Note = "No correction"
            Range("H3").Value = Note
        
        'Correction according to ISO16032 when X = between 4 and 10'
        Case 3.6 To 10.5
            Result = Range("K3")
            Range("G3").Value = Result
            Note = "Correction per ISO16032"
            Range("H3").Value = Note
        
        'Maximal correction value set to 2,2 dB if X < 4'
        Case 0.1 To 3.5
            Result = Range("L3")
            Range("G3").Value = Result
            Note = "Correction limit set to 2,2 dB"
            Range("H3").Value = Note
        
        'If x = < 0, the measurement is invalid'
        Case Else
            Note = "Repeat measurement!"
            Range("H3").Value = Note
    
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: So, do you need a global solution to allow processing of any column (initially setting it), for all its existing rows? If so, what about "Range("H3").Value = Note"? Should this H:H column be used for any processed column, or should it be calculated like a two columns to the right of the used one (H against F, L against J and so on). Then, in your code there are more columns involved F, G, K, L... How to proceed, from this point of view, in case of another initial column? I asked about other columns seeing your example of desired range (Range("J3") value to Range("J3:J52"))...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, I think that a simple loop, with the addition of an argument to your ISO function allows you to solve your problem like this

```
Sub Looping()
    For i = 3 To 52
        ' Convert i to String because we need to concatenate with the letter F, G, H...
        Call ISO16032(CStr(i))
    Next
End Sub

Function ISO16032(Cell_X)
   
    'DeltaL Range'
    Dim DeltaL As Range
    Set DeltaL = Range("F" + Cell_X)
    'Result is the corrected value in G column'
    Dim Result As Long
    'Note is the calc note in H column'
    Dim Note As String
    'X is the DeltaL between noise and background noise'
    Dim x As Long
    x = Range("F" + Cell_X).Value
    
    Select Case Range("F" + Cell_X).Value
    
        'No correction when X = > 10'
        Case 10.6 To 200
            Result = Range("J" + Cell_X)
            Range("G" + Cell_X).Value = Result
            Note = "No correction"
            Range("H" + Cell_X).Value = Note
        
        'Correction according to ISO16032 when X = between 4 and 10'
        Case 3.6 To 10.5
            Result = Range("K" + Cell_X)
            Range("G" + Cell_X).Value = Result
            Note = "Correction per ISO16032"
            Range("H" + Cell_X).Value = Note
        
        'Maximal correction value set to 2,2 dB if X < 4'
        Case 0.1 To 3.5
            Result = Range("L" + Cell_X)
            Range("G" + Cell_X).Value = Result
            Note = "Correction limit set to 2,2 dB"
            Range("H" + Cell_X).Value = Note
        
        'If x = < 0, the measurement is invalid'
        Case Else
            Note = "Repeat measurement!"
            Range("H" + Cell_X).Value = Note

    End Select

End Function
```

EDIT: think indented your code like I did to make it more readable too (or like @Darren Bartrup-Cook did when editing your question)

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem and seems to be working very fast!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an example of how to calculate each row.
Just getting your code to work across multiple rows.

[Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells)
[With...End With Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement)

```
'No need for Sub to call function that doesn't return anything.... just write a sub.
Public Sub ISO16032()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim RowCounter As Long
        Dim Result As Long
        Dim Note As String
        'Only calculate if there is data in rows 3 onwards.
        If LastRow >= 3 Then
            'Reset results on each pass.
            'Assuming -1 is an impossible answer so code knows
            'not to put anything on Case Else.
            Result = -1
            Note = ""
            'Cycle through each row and calculate.
            For RowCounter = 3 To LastRow
                Select Case .Cells(RowCounter, 6) 'Look at column F(column 6) on each row.
                    Case 10.6 To 200
                        Result = .Cells(RowCounter, 10)
                        Note = "No corrections."
                    Case 3.6 To 10.5
                        Result = .Cells(RowCounter, 11)
                        Note = "Correction per ISO16032"
                    Case 0.1 To 3.5
                        Result = .Cells(RowCounter, 12)
                        Note = "Correction limit set to 2,2 dB"
                    Case Else
                        Note = "Repeat measurement!"
                End Select
                'Place results on sheet.
                .Cells(RowCounter, 7) = IIf(Result >= 0, Result, "")
                .Cells(RowCounter, 8) = Note
            Next RowCounter
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful in trying to understand how to "navigate" cells in my VBA code!